# Remove all observations of a group when a specific value is not the same across all observations of the group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data sets. One contains patients and their diagnoses over time; the other contains patients and drugs administered.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Patient = c("John", "John", "John", "Jane", "Jane", "Mary", "Mary"),
  Year = c(2018, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2018, 2018),
  Diagnosis = c("a","b","a","b","a","a","a")#,
  #DiagnosticAccuracy = c("high", "low", "high", "high", "low", "high", "low")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  Patient = c("John", "John", "Jane", "Jane", "Mary"),
  Year = c(2018, 2019, 2018, 2021, 2018),
  Medication = c("Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug B", "Drug B")
)
```

I want to match diagnoses and drugs unambiguously. The problem is that the data contains only one drug per year for each patient, but a patient can have any number of diagnoses yearly. Thus, I don't know which diagnosis the drug was administered for when a patient has more than one unique diagnosis in a year. So if there is uncertainty, i. e. more than one diagnosis per patient and year, I want to eliminate that group from my data.

```
library(dplyr)

df_merge <- df1 %>%
  full_join(., df2, by=c("Patient", "Year"))

df_merge 

  Patient Year Diagnosis Medication
1    John 2018         a     Drug A
2    John 2018         b     Drug A
3    John 2019         a     Drug A
4    Jane 2020         b       <NA>
5    Jane 2021         a     Drug B
6    Mary 2018         a     Drug B
7    Mary 2018         a     Drug B
8    Jane 2018      <NA>     Drug A
```

In this example, I cannot tell whether John received his one recorded drug in 2018 for diagnosis "a" or "b". Thus I want his record of 2018 deleted. Mary has had two diagnoses in 2018 as well. But as both diagnoses were the same, it doesn't matter; I know which diagnosis her "Drug B" was administered for. As both of Mary's records are duplicates, I want only to keep one observation. In more or less plain English, my rule should be something like that:

"If the values in a specific column are NOT the same across ALL rows of a Patient-Year-group, that group shall be discarded" … and duplicates be removed but I know that much … ;-)

Per this rule, my desired data set looks like this:

```
  Patient Year Diagnosis Medication
1    John 2019         a     Drug A
2    Jane 2020         b       <NA>
3    Jane 2021         a     Drug B
4    Mary 2018         a     Drug B
5    Jane 2018      <NA>     Drug A
```

I hope I have made my problem sufficiently clear … Solutions using any package are welcome.

EDIT: I ran into a problem and had to add a variable to my example data. I don't know what the correct conduct in this case is, so I added this variable and commented it out.

Anyway, I have a variable "diagnostic accuracy". If there is a "low"-accuracy diagnosis at the same time as a "high"-accuracy diagnosis, the "low" observation shall be discarded. My desired data frame would look like this:

```
  Patient Year Diagnosis DiagnosticAccuracy Medication
1    John 2019         a               high     Drug A
2    Jane 2020         b               high       <NA>
3    Jane 2021         a                low     Drug B
4    Mary 2018         a               high     Drug B
5    Jane 2018      <NA>               <NA>     Drug A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do this with some joins.

Step 1 - Remove rows from `df2` which has more than 1 `Diagnosis` in `df1` for `Patient-Year` combo. This is done using `anti_join`. We create `new_df2` with it.

Step 2 - Keep only 1 `Diagnosis` patient for each `Patient-Year` combo in `df1` and join it with new `df2` to get the result.

```
library(dplyr)

new_df2 <- df2 %>%
  anti_join(df1 %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Diagnosis) > 1, .by = c(Patient, Year)) %>%
  distinct(Patient, Year), by = join_by(Patient, Year)) 

df1 %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Diagnosis) == 1, .by = c(Patient, Year)) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  full_join(new_df2, by = join_by(Patient, Year))
  

#  Patient Year Diagnosis Medication
#1    John 2019         a     Drug A
#2    Jane 2020         b       <NA>
#3    Jane 2021         a     Drug B
#4    Mary 2018         a     Drug B
#5    Jane 2018      <NA>     Drug A
```

Comment: Hey Ronak! In my real data, there is one extra variable "diagnostic accuracy" which makes this splendid approach not work correctly but I can't work it out without cumbersome workarounds. Would you mind taking a look at the edit in the original post?